# Check for Mandatory Fields for different column

Tags: excel, vba

I have to create a macro in book1. I have 3 excel files (book1, book2, and book3).

Book3 is a template and shows the 5 elements (ID, Name, Birthday, Address, Tel) and whether these are mandatory.

The macro should open book2 to check whether the element has a value. If all the mandatory elements in book2 contain a value, cell `B1` in Book1 will indicate complete data with the value 'pass'. If not, 'Fail' will be shown in the same cell. How can I achieve this?

[image]

```
Sub check()

Dim ExternalWb1 As Workbook
Dim msg As String
Dim rng As Range
Set ExternalWb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\A9905681\Desktop\XY's\Wk 10\Test_Mandatory\Book2.xlsx")
Dim ExternalSheet1 As Worksheet
Set ExternalSheet1 = ExternalWb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ExternalSheet1.Range("B2:B5")

For Each cell In rng
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        Sheet1.Range("B1") = "Pass"
    Else
        Sheet1.Range("B1") = "Fail"
    End If
Next cell

ExternalWb1.Close
End Sub
```

For now I'm only able to check specific range for example range ("B2:B5") in book2.

Comment: Please can you show what you have attempted so far.

Comment: SO is *not* a free code writing service. If you've made an attempt yourself, please add it to your question and tell us what's not working. Asking users to write the entire project for you is not appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should help you out:

```
Option Explicit
Sub check()

    'First lets store the mandatory items
    Dim Mandatory As New Scripting.Dictionary 'You need Microsoft Scripting Runtime library under tools-->references
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    arr = Workbooks("Book3.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value 'store the sheet inside the array
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr) 'loop through the data and store the mandatory items
        If arr(i, 1) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'force an exit if the row has an empty value on column A
        If arr(i, 2) = "Yes" Then 'if the item is mandatory, store it
            Mandatory.Add arr(i, 1), 1
        End If
    Next i

    'lets check every item in the book2
    'For this one to work properly you MUST not have empty rows, the UsedRange must be the same as rows you have
    'When having data and then clearing it, the usedrange remains the same, you must delete the empty rows.
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Header As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\A9905681\Desktop\XY's\Wk 10\Test_Mandatory\Book2.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
    arr = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value
    'Loop through columns and rows
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2) 'loop through columns
        Header = arr(1, i)
        If Mandatory.Exists(Header) Then 'will loop only through mandatory items
            For i = 2 To UBound(arr) 'loop through rows
                If arr(i, j) = vbNullString Then 'once we find one item not filled
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2) = "Fail" 'fill the cell with fail
                    Exit Sub 'end the procedure
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next j

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2) = "Pass" 'if nothing happens above, we put Pass to the cell
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

The code is commented, but if you need help feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want! Thank you so much =D